How to correctly use `useMemo` hook in the specific case to only perform calculation once?
I have the trouble resolving the issue described below. I tried to use useMemo, but seems like I'm using it in a wrong way.
I've created custom hook that should do some expensive calculation on a huge object and return it, used useMemo hook to reduce re-calculations:
// just for example
// retrieved API call or some other place, not generated here
const hugeData = new Array(100).fill(1000);

const useCalculationHook = (dependency) => {
  // useMemo will should only re-calculate when dependency changes
  const sum = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("re-calculated", dependency);
    return expensiveCalculation(hugeData, dependency);
  }, [dependency]);

  return sum;
};

I want the hook above to return the already calculated result when given the same dependency.
useCalculationHook(1) // re-calculate
useCalculationHook(2) // re-calculate
useCalculationHook(3) // re-calculate
useCalculationHook(1) // return cached-result

The results are saved between re-renders and that really gives the boost to my app when I render a huge list of the component that uses the useCalculationHook but initial re-calculation happens every time no matter what I give as dependency.
I know that that I can do it manually by saving the results in object and using it, but if there is a "React" way I definitely prefer to implement that.
Or... is there any library where I can manually cache results?
Example on Codesandbox * See the console to see when it re-calculates the useMemo.

It sounds like you should simply be holding your state in a parent or context, but if you are going to use this hook it would help to know what you're passing as a dependency? The Codesandbox link isn't working.

sure, updated link


I know that that I can do it manually by saving the results in object and using it, but if there is a "React" way I definitely prefer to implement that.

There is no "React way" for this. The useMemo hook only caches a single value between re-renders, it does not store all old values to quickly look them up. The dependency array is not used as a cache key, but simply to indicate when a re-calculation will be necessary.
If you want to memoise that expensiveCalculation yourself, just do it. Think about what cache keys you want to use (and what their data types will be), whether to cache globally or in each component, and how many results you want to keep in the cache or whether there is a memory size constraint. There's a few libraries that can help you solve these, but I won't make any recommendations here. If you want to do it per-component, just store the cache object in a useRef.
